# Problems with editing VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I can't edit the code after pressing ctrl+c or after I minimized the window and opened the code. this cursor appears highlighted in the photo and nothing happens so that it doesn't click. How to solve the problem?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eEuZE.png)

Answer (score 0):

You have the vim plugin installed.

Either press `i` to go into edit mode, or disable the extension in the `Extensions` tab.

[image]